# awk: change whitespaces with tabs taking titles and empty fields into account

Tags: awk, tabs

I have a space-separated file that I want to turn into a tab-separated file. The file looks like this:

```
pos    peptide      logscore affinity(nM) Bind Level    Protein Name     Allele
0   GPSGGQPX         0.075        22266                          1 HLA-A11:01
0   PSGGQPXA         0.071        23285                          2 HLA-A11:01
0   SGGQPXAL         0.076        21945                          3 HLA-A11:01
0   GGQPXALD         0.076        21858                          4 HLA-A11:01
0   GQPXALDS         0.075        22237                          5 HLA-A11:01
0   QPXALDSG         0.073        22748                          6 HLA-A11:01
0   PXALDSGY         0.072        22962                          7 HLA-A11:01
0   XALDSGYD         0.080        21133                          8 HLA-A11:01
0   DTSMKDMH         0.093        18194                          9 HLA-A11:01
0   TSMKDMHK         0.732           18         SB              10 HLA-A11:01
0   SMKDMHKV         0.099        17148                         11 HLA-A11:01
0   MKDMHKVL         0.071        23175                         12 HLA-A11:01
0   KDMHKVLR         0.135        11550                         13 HLA-A11:01
0   DMHKVLRT         0.074        22537                         14 HLA-A11:01
0   MHKVLRTL         0.072        23056                         15 HLA-A11:01
0   HKVLRTLQ         0.069        23819                         16 HLA-A11:01
0   DTSMKDMH         0.093        18194                         17 HLA-A11:01
0   TSMKDMHK         0.732           18         SB              18 HLA-A11:01
0   SMKDMHKV         0.099        17148                         19 HLA-A11:01
0   MKDMHKVL         0.071        23175                         20 HLA-A11:01
```

I have to replace whitespaces with a single tab, taking into account:

1. no tab in "Bind Name" and in "Protein Name" in the title line; they should be renamed "Bind.Level" and "Protein.Name" instead.
2. 2 tabs instead of just 1 (or a "-" or NA in the middle) between the affinity field and the Protein.Name field in those entries where Bind.Level is empty, to preserve such empty entries in that field.

Hence, just the following isn't enough:

```
 awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this with a one-liner, preferably awk?

**EDIT:**

This is how the output should look like, notice "Bind.Level" and "Protein.Name" in the title, and "-" (which can be NA or "") in the empty Bind.Level records

```
pos peptide logscore    affinity(nM)    Bind.Level  Protein.Name    Allele
0   GPSGGQPX    0.075   22266   -   1   HLA-A11:01
0   PSGGQPXA    0.071   23285   -   2   HLA-A11:01
0   SGGQPXAL    0.076   21945   -   3   HLA-A11:01
0   GGQPXALD    0.076   21858   -   4   HLA-A11:01
0   GQPXALDS    0.075   22237   -   5   HLA-A11:01
0   QPXALDSG    0.073   22748   -   6   HLA-A11:01
0   PXALDSGY    0.072   22962   -   7   HLA-A11:01
0   XALDSGYD    0.080   21133   -   8   HLA-A11:01
0   DTSMKDMH    0.093   18194   -   9   HLA-A11:01
0   TSMKDMHK    0.732   18  SB  10  HLA-A11:01
0   SMKDMHKV    0.099   17148   -   11  HLA-A11:01
0   MKDMHKVL    0.071   23175   -   12  HLA-A11:01
0   KDMHKVLR    0.135   11550   -   13  HLA-A11:01
0   DMHKVLRT    0.074   22537   -   14  HLA-A11:01
0   MHKVLRTL    0.072   23056   -   15  HLA-A11:01
0   HKVLRTLQ    0.069   23819   -   16  HLA-A11:01
0   DTSMKDMH    0.093   18194   -   17  HLA-A11:01
0   TSMKDMHK    0.732   18  SB  18  HLA-A11:01
0   SMKDMHKV    0.099   17148   -   19  HLA-A11:01
0   MKDMHKVL    0.071   23175   -   20  HLA-A11:01
```

Note that non-empty Bind.Level records might adopt different values, not just "SB"... but all of them alphabetic... Protein.Name might not always be numeric, though...

It would be something like identifying the fields separated by \s+; then, if there are 7 fields, print them as such (separated by tab), and if there are 6 (Bind.Level empty), print $1, $2, $3, $4, "-", $5, $6. Protein.names could potentially contain spaces, but I'm going to make sure it they don't (they are the input). That should be super simple, but I don't know how to do it... anyone??

Comment: Can you post how the output should look like?

Comment: sure, let me edit it real quick

Comment: edited to show the intended output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it in 2 steps, a first step to add "-" in the empty Binding.Level records and "." in the proper title names, and a second step to change from whitespaces to tabs:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS=FS};($50==" "){$50="-"};(NR==1){$47="."; $64="."}{print}' file > out1
 awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" out1 > out2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to handle fields using `gnu awk`

```
awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="4 17 13 14 16 13" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/ +|\t+/,"",$i);$5=$5?$5:"-";print }' file
pos peptidel ogscoreaffin ity(nM)BindL evelProtein NameAlle
0 GPSGGQPX 0.075 22266 - 1HLA-A11:01
0 PSGGQPXA 0.071 23285 - 2HLA-A11:01
0 SGGQPXAL 0.076 21945 - 3HLA-A11:01
0 GGQPXALD 0.076 21858 - 4HLA-A11:01
0 GQPXALDS 0.075 22237 - 5HLA-A11:01
0 QPXALDSG 0.073 22748 - 6HLA-A11:01
0 PXALDSGY 0.072 22962 - 7HLA-A11:01
0 XALDSGYD 0.080 21133 - 8HLA-A11:01
0 DTSMKDMH 0.093 18194 - 9HLA-A11:01
0 TSMKDMHK 0.732 18 SB 10HLA-A11:01
0 SMKDMHKV 0.099 17148 - 11HLA-A11:01
0 MKDMHKVL 0.071 23175 - 12HLA-A11:01
0 KDMHKVLR 0.135 11550 - 13HLA-A11:01
0 DMHKVLRT 0.074 22537 - 14HLA-A11:01
0 MHKVLRTL 0.072 23056 - 15HLA-A11:01
0 HKVLRTLQ 0.069 23819 - 16HLA-A11:01
0 DTSMKDMH 0.093 18194 - 17HLA-A11:01
0 TSMKDMHK 0.732 18 SB 18HLA-A11:01
0 SMKDMHKV 0.099 17148 - 19HLA-A11:01
0 MKDMHKVL 0.071 23175 - 20HLA-A11:01
```

or

```
awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="4 17 13 14 16 13" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/ +|\t+/,"",$i);$5=$5?$5:"-";print}' file | column -t
pos  peptidel  ogscoreaffin  ity(nM)BindL  evelProtein  NameAlle
0    GPSGGQPX  0.075         22266         -            1HLA-A11:01
0    PSGGQPXA  0.071         23285         -            2HLA-A11:01
0    SGGQPXAL  0.076         21945         -            3HLA-A11:01
0    GGQPXALD  0.076         21858         -            4HLA-A11:01
0    GQPXALDS  0.075         22237         -            5HLA-A11:01
0    QPXALDSG  0.073         22748         -            6HLA-A11:01
0    PXALDSGY  0.072         22962         -            7HLA-A11:01
0    XALDSGYD  0.080         21133         -            8HLA-A11:01
0    DTSMKDMH  0.093         18194         -            9HLA-A11:01
0    TSMKDMHK  0.732         18            SB           10HLA-A11:01
0    SMKDMHKV  0.099         17148         -            11HLA-A11:01
0    MKDMHKVL  0.071         23175         -            12HLA-A11:01
0    KDMHKVLR  0.135         11550         -            13HLA-A11:01
0    DMHKVLRT  0.074         22537         -            14HLA-A11:01
0    MHKVLRTL  0.072         23056         -            15HLA-A11:01
0    HKVLRTLQ  0.069         23819         -            16HLA-A11:01
0    DTSMKDMH  0.093         18194         -            17HLA-A11:01
0    TSMKDMHK  0.732         18            SB           18HLA-A11:01
0    SMKDMHKV  0.099         17148         -            19HLA-A11:01
0    MKDMHKVL  0.071         23175         -            20HLA-A11:01
```

This way you can format it the way you want, since you can control what fields is what size.

Comment: I would avoid field widths though, cause I don't know exactly from where to where they should go, bigger numbers might appear

Comment: @DaniCee First row is wrong due to it does not follow the rest of the data regarding field with.  It can be handled separately.